# find the customer type and direct to relevent information

Tags: forms, authentication, expressionengine

I am developing a site to sell some beverages to retail customers and wholesale customers.

I want to keep a log in form in landing page which help both customers to access site according their customer type (retail or wholesale)

I used member:log in_form and check my member_group.  It is “1” because I already log in into my system.

Is this possible in EE:  Create a Button for retail and button for wholesale.  Then when a customer click a button system pick customer choice and give access to relevant member group using code snippet below.

```
{if member_group == 7}
  Access to Retail group
{/if: elseif member_group == 8}
  Access to wholesale group
{if:else}
  Welcome to our site.
{/if}
```

If it is not possible can you please guide me to the right track. I am new to EE.

Comment: When I have created sites that were retail/wholesale we had 2 pricing sets. You don't want to show the wholesale price to the retail customers.  Therefore anyone can sign up for an account, but every new EE account is retail.  We then manually promoted members to "wholesale" if they appeared to be legitimate wholesalers.  In general tho what you are asking is very much easily done in EE and you are on the right track.  You should consider carefully whether you different member groups get different pages (templates) or the same pages with different content.

Comment: Final sentence above is omits a word: You should consider carefully whether you want different member groups get different pages (templates) or the same pages with different content.

Answer (score 1):

What your suggesting is exactly the way to do it, with just a little change in the code:

```
{if member_group == 7}
  Access to Retail group
{if:elseif member_group == 8}
  Access to wholesale group
{if:else}
  Welcome to our site.
{/if}
```

Note the change in line 3 - just a few typos.

Advanced conditionals are notoriously slow though, so look into Mark Croxton's Switchee for speed. You can more easily create entire blocks and case-test them en-masse with Switchee, and it's far faster overall than working on a per-component basis.